# Why Snowpack is not taking my type declaration files?

Tags: typescript, babeljs, snowpack

I have the following configuration in snowpack:

```js
/** @type {import("snowpack").SnowpackUserConfig } */
module.exports = {
  mount: {
        public:{ url: '/', static: true },
        src: { url: '/dist' },
        runtime: { url: '/runtime' },
  },
  plugins: [
        '@snowpack/plugin-typescript',
        ['@snowpack/plugin-babel', 
            {
                'input': ['.ts', '.tsx'],
            }
        ]
  ],
  packageOptions: {
    /* ... */
  },
  devOptions: {
    /* ... */
  },
  buildOptions: {
    /* ... */
  },
};
```

And this is in my Declaration file `index.d.ts` but Snowpack is not reading it when I start the dev server.

```js
declare global {
    namespace JSX {
        interface IntrinsicElements {
            [elName: string]: any;
        }
    }
}
```

The only way to get it working is changing the file name to `index.ts`

Answer (score -1):

The way you've phrased the question - snowpack 'not taking' your .d.ts files - is a bit vague for me. If you mean that your editor (assuming VSCode) is not giving you autocompletion then try to add the file to the "include" array in your tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "include": [
        ...
        "index.d.ts",
    ]
}
```

I found this solution from the basic typescript template used by the create-snowpack-app CLI tool:
https://github.com/snowpackjs/snowpack/tree/main/create-snowpack-app/app-template-blank-typescript
There the .d.ts file is inside 'types' folder, and that folder is then included in tsconfig.

Comment: @Montana Seems a fair question -- I'm not 100% sure what you're asking either. Does this answer help? If not, how not? Etc.